# Search Form giving errors via Validator

Tags: wordpress, forms, search

I seared for and found your webpage where someone had the same problem. Their post was [xhtml Search Form giving errors via Validator, need some help? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006603/xhtml-search-form-giving-errors-via-validator-need-some-help-closed) was closed with no solution. I have the same problem. When I close Internet Explorer it gives me the folowing error several times:

```
Message: Object required
Line: 53
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI:
```

When I checked with the Explorer Developer Tools Line 53 is the search form code.
Would really appreciate some help as it is very annoying. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Object is probably referring to a missing object from a class in the php, at a guess from what you have said, have you edited the search script at all?

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the reply. No I did not edit the search script, but I found some other questions from people who had the same problem and found some instructions on resetting plugins on http://codex.wordpress.org/. It gave two methods, one via FTP which I tried because it was easier than doing it one by one individually and the error disappeared. Thanks.